# How to display login and logout time of employee in tableau within same sheet?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have a dataset which contains the login and logout time of each employee in sql. The requirement is to create a dashboard which will display the login and logout info of each employee. I have created a dashboard which display the login and logout time in different sheets. How can I get this information in single sheet ?

Edit------------------------------------------

Sheet in tableau.

Code:

```
if{FIXED [DatePart],[EmployeeID]: MIN([TimePart])} = [TimePart] then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

//Using this code i have got first login of each employee for each day.

Code:

```
if{FIXED [DatePart],[EmployeeID]:MAX([TimePart])} = [TimePart] then 'Y' else 'N' END
```

//Using this code i have got last logout of each employee on each day.

So i have to display login and logout of each employee in tableau

Comment: Can you define what is a sheet for you, Excel ? a table in a website ? If you have the dataset with 2 columns and know how to display each column, the job is almost done. Can you provide some code ?it may help us provide an answer

Comment: Sheet in tableau. Code: if{FIXED [DatePart],[EmployeeID]: MIN([TimePart])} = [TimePart] then 'Y' else 'N' end.  Using this code i have got first login of each employee for each day.  Code: if{FIXED [DatePart],[EmployeeID]:MAX([TimePart])} = [TimePart] then 'Y' else 'N' END. Using this code i have got last logout of each employee on each day. So i have to display login and logout of each employee in tableau

Comment: It is possible but need some sample data, Can you share the workbook with dummy data?